# How to connect EEPROM to Raspberry Pi 3?

Tags: raspbian, gpio, rpi.gpio, eeprom

I was wondering on how to connect an EEPROM chip to the Raspberry Pi 3? And any suggestions on which EEPROM chip model is best to use with RPi3?

Comment: I would recommend this one: https://pl.aliexpress.com/item/32263147137.html

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think it's an objective question unless you clearly state what you are trying to achieve and what are the criteria for "best".

Answer (score 1):

Most EEPROM chips use either [SPI](https://pinout.xyz/pinout/spi#) or [I2C](https://pinout.xyz/pinout/i2c#) to transfer data, check the docs for the chip you choose to find out which and connect to the appropriate bus on the Pi. From there it's a matter of sending the right commands on the right bus -- again the chip docs will help with this.

There is, no doubt, many Python libraries to help with the commands (e.g. https://github.com/headamage/EEPROM-PiPython) or you could try the device-tree bindings for EEPROM chips: https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/tree/rpi-4.19.y/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/eeprom

I've no specific experience on this but there might be a caveat: if you choose an I2C EEPROM avoid the temptation to use the second I2C bus, this is reserved for [HATs](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/introducing-raspberry-pi-hats/).

Comment: Or if you insist to use more than one I2C bus, you can use Rpi4B buster, which has 5 (but only the first 3 are stable).  But release 2019sep26 might have solved the problem.  So for Rpi4B, you don't have any reason to use the I2C channel 0 which belong to the HAT EEPROM.